# Transparent 1 pixel high line in title bar

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 and gnome-shell. 
On my second screen there is a transparent line above and under the title bar, as you can see in the picture. (you can see the Ubuntu Wallpaper)

I only installed Ubuntu, the driver for my graphic card (nvidia 367.57) and the gnome-shell. 
I even reinstalled all, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: It's not only on my second screen, its on my main screen too.

Comment: But only in full screen mode, otherwise  if the title bar "hits" the upper screen end (e.g. with two windows left/right), there is only one transparent line above the window.